# Concatenate files based off unique titles in their first column

Tags: awk, sed

I have many files that are of two column format with a label in the first column and a number in the second column. The number is positive (never zero):

```
AGS    3
KET    45
WEGWET    12
FEW    56
```

*Within each file*, the labels are not repeated.

I would like to concatenate these many files into one file with many+1 columns, such that the first column includes the unique set of all labels across all files, and the last five columns include the number for each label of each file. If the label did not exist in a certain file (and hence there is no number for it), I would like it to default to zero. For instance, if the second file contains this:

```
AGS    5
KET    14
KJV    2
FEW    3
```

then the final output would look like:

```
AGS    3    5
KET    45   14
WEGWET    12    0
KJV    0    2
FEW    56    3
```

I am new to Linux, and have been playing around with sed and awk, but realize this probably requires multiple steps...

*Edit note: I had to change it from just 2 files to many files. Even though my example only shows 2 files, I would like to do this in case of >2 files as well. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data are in files named `file1` and `file2`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=0; next} {a[$1]+=0; b[$1]=$2} END{for (x in b) {printf "%-15s%3s%3s\n",x,a[x],b[x]}}' file1 file2
KJV      0  2
WEGWET  12  0
KET     45 14
AGS      3  5
FEW     56  3
```

To understand the above, we have to understand an `awk` trick.
In `awk`, `NR` is the number of records (lines) that have been processed and `FNR` is the number of records that we have processed in the current file.  Consequently, the condition `FNR==NR` is true only when we are processing in the first file.  In this case, the associative array `a` gets all the values from the first file and associative array `b` gets placeholder, i.e. zero, values.  When we process the second file, its values go in array `b` and we make sure that array `a` at least has a placeholder value of zero.  When we are done with the second file, the data is printed.

#### More than two files using GNU Awk

I created a file3:

```
$ cat file3
AGS    3
KET    45
WEGWET    12
FEW    56
AGS 17
ABC 100
```

The awk program extended to work with any number of files is:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 {n+=1} {a[$1][n]=$2} END{for (x in a) {printf "%-15s",x; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {printf "%5s",a[x][i]};print ""}}' file1 file2 file3
KJV             2     
ABC                100
WEGWET    12        12
KET       45   14   45
AGS        3    5   17
FEW       56    3   56
```

This code works creates a file counter.  We know that we are in a new file every time that `FNR` is `1` and a counter, `n`, is incremented.  For every line we encounter, we put the data in a 2-D array.  The first dimension of `a` is the label and the second is the number of the file that we encountered it in.  In the end, we just loop over all the labels and all the files, from 1 to `n` and print the data.

#### More than 2 files *without* GNU Awk

Without requiring GNU's awk, we can solve the problem using simulated two-dimensional arrays:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 {n+=1} {b[$1]=1; a[$1,":",n]=$2} END{for (x in b) {printf "%-15s",x; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {q=a[x,":",i]+0; printf "%5s",q};print ""}}' file1 file2 file3
KJV                0    2    0
ABC                0    0  100
WEGWET            12    0   12
KET               45   14   45
AGS                3    5   17
FEW               56    3   56
```

Comment: Would this work for >2 files? Where I would simply change the ending part from "file1 file2" to "file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6"

Comment: Oh, I just read your helpful note below the code. For some reason, I did not see it earlier. Thank you!!

Comment: Yes, I think it only works for two files. I am sorry I did not specify that I had more than that...

Comment: Thank you very much. But I get an error: awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 FNR==1 {n+=1} >>>  {a[$1][ <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: I just copied the line from the answer to a shell and it works for me (linux, GNU awk).  What OS are you on?

Comment: I am not sure if this could be the problem, but the first column label can be long (like up to 12 characters) and include both numbers, letters, and other symbols...

Comment: @user3603093 OK.  I have updated it for wide labels.

Comment: It looks so great! Thank you... The only other thing is that I wanted it to default to zero if there was no counts in that particular file. (So that the is at least one value in every column of each row).

Comment: From what I get in the output, there is simply no value printed in those columns that did not have a number.

Comment: @user3603093 OK, I just added zeros to the Mac solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0;next}
{
    print (($1 in a)?a[$1] FS $2: $1 FS "0" FS $2)
    delete a[$1]
}
END{
    for (x in a) print a[x],"0"
}' file1 file2 | column -t
AGS     3   5
KET     45  14
KJV     0   2
FEW     56  3
WEGWET  12  0
```

- You read file1 in to an array indexed at column 1 and assign entire line as it's value
- For the file2, check if column 1 is present in our array. If it is print the value from file1 along with value from file2. If it is not present print `0` as value for file1.
- Delete the array element as we go along to get only what was unique in file1.
- In the `END` block print what was unique in file1 and print 0 for file2.
- Pipe the output to `column -t` for pretty format.

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you think this would work for multiple files? So that I could simply change that part "file1 file2 | column -t" to "file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 | column -t"

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention it is more than 2 files. I just used 2 as an example to make it easier to put an example output onto here... :o)